# How to open SQL DB like Excel?

Tags: sql, mariadb

excuse my utter ignorance when it comes to SQL. But I just want a quick, easy table edit in a .SQL db. I've tried some opensource editing tools, but they all seem to want me to install a localhost SQL server... I don't have time for this. I just need to quickly open it like a Excel/Access file and edit a few rows/columns of data. It's a MariaDB.

Any advice? Thank you.

I've tried some opensource editing tools. I expect to quickly open it like a Excel/Access file

Comment: Then why don't you use Excel or Microsoft Access? MariaDB is a client/server RDBMS, not a desktop application.

Comment: FYI, MariaDB and MySQL are different products. I've changed the tag on your question from mysql to mariadb, since you said you are using MariaDB.

Comment: Well I assume its MariaDB. What can you recommend as a tool for me to open SQL dbs easily?

Comment: In the header it says: MySQL dump 10.19  Distrib 10.3.36-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64).

Comment: @valeclee This is a dump (not clear if from MySQL or MariaDB). A dump is a backup file that contains all the info for the re-creation of the entire DB (or a part of it). You cannot open a dump file as it was an Excel file. You have to ask the DB type (MySQL or MariaDB) to whom produced that dump and install a local server to import the dump and navigate through tables. I don't know other ways. Sorry

Comment: If you don't have time to install a local server (which, in most cases, is easy as at the moment on the web you can find lots of ready-to-use software - like MAMP for MySQL), you should (if is possible) ask the person who created the file to export the tables as Excel or CSV file instead of providing you a dump

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you have a dump file, probably with a `.sql` extension. This is basically a text file containing SQL statements like CREATE TABLE and INSERT, which could be used to load data into a MariaDB database. But the SQL statements in the dump file include syntax that is *only* compatible with MariaDB. It can't be loaded into for example Microsoft Access without extensive edits.

In my opinion, it's less effort to install MariaDB Server, load the data, and then [use Microsoft Access as a client](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mariadb-odbc-access-linked-tables.rst).

But you said you don't want to be bothered with installing the SQL server, so I guess you get to edit the dump file using a text editor, and change syntax from MariaDB flavor of SQL to Microsoft Access flavor of SQL.

Have fun!

Comment: I just managed to open it with Notepad ++, but loading the table section is extremely slow, and I would have to scroll far to the right to see the data. Isn't there any software that opens and edits it as easy as Notepad++ with good tables views like Excel?

PS. I just realized i don't have Access installed

Comment: I'm afraid not. You have a data file that requires specific software to use it. You're unwilling to install or use that software, so that's the end of the story. Bye!

Comment: Then how come Notepad++ can do it? Surely there must be a piece of software that does the same but arranges the data into tables like excel and access. hard to believe such a thing wouldnt exist.

Comment: @valeclee A `.sql` file is a plain text file containing instructions for a database server. It is not designed to be read outright, it is designed to be executed. Asking "how come Notepad++ can open a `.sql` file but Excel can't?" is like asking "how come Notepad++ can open a `.cpp` file but Excel can't?" It might contain human-readable text, but C++ program source code isn't a spreadsheet, regardless of the fact that you can read it in a text editor. Likewise, an SQL dump isn't a spreadsheet.

Comment: @valeclee, Another example is that you can open a Microsoft Word document in Notepad++. But it'll look like nonsense, because Notepad++ doesn't know how to display the rich text, metadata, styles, and structure that Word document files contain. This shouldn't be a surprise or a mystery to you.